# changing form action based on the radio button outside the form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am generating forms based on the data from the database. so a set of data is basically a form with a button to select the data. Based on another radio button selection, I want to do different operations on the form data. Is it possible to do it?

```
<form action="">
  <p>Please select user gender:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
</form>

<?php

// here I am generating a list of forms based on some information.
// $fetched_data is the returned array of data (data from db)

// how do I change the form action of the following forms based on the radio buttons above ???

if(!empty($fetched_data))
{
  foreach ($fetched_data as $row)
  {

?>
    <form action = '??????' method =get>
    <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $row["job_options"]; ?>  </td>
        <td><?php  echo $row["salary_options"]; ?>  </td>
        <td><?php  echo $row["place_options"]; ?>  </td>
// buttons
        <td><input type="hidden" name="getID" value=<?php  echo $row["id"]; ?> /></td>
        <td><input type=submit name=serialSubmit value=select id=button1 class = classSubmit /></td>
    </tr>

    </form>
    
<?php
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you use a `javascript` solution?

Comment: @jpneey yes. I just want a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I'll use a select rather than checkboxes

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <p>Please select user gender:</p>
    <select class="gender-select">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then listen on changes of that select:

```
<script>
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.gender-select');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const selectedGender = event.target.value;
    // then we can change to form's action based on the selected value here
    if (selectedGender == 'male') {
        document.getElementById('form').action = 'http://action/for/male.php';
        return;
    }
    if (selectedGender == 'female') {
        document.getElementById('form').action = 'http://action/for/female.php';
        return;
    }
    // if others
    document.getElementById('form').action = 'http://action/for/others.php';
});
</script>
```

This script can be **greatly** optimized and compressed, I'm just gonna leave it this way so it is much more easier to understand